# how to add echo variable inside other variable from other file?

Tags: php

I am making static php and i want somthing like this (i am a php beginner :):

From this:
`<?php $titleid="example title"; ?>`

To this:
`<?php $title="<?php echo $titleid; ?>"; ?>`

To get this:
`<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>`

And then, the expected output is:

`<h1>example title</h1>`

I use this cause the variable `$titleid` is in other php file.

Comment: The question is very unclear. What exactly are you asking? `$foo = 'bar';`  stores the string `bar` in the variable `$foo`. If you want to echo that string, just do `echo $foo;`. If you want to put the string in the variable `$foo` in another variable, just do: `$newFoo = $foo;`.

Comment: When you say "in other php file", do you mean an included php file, or an entirely different file? If the 2 variables are in the same scope you can simply assign `<?php $title = $titleid; ?>` if you _need_ a different variable.

Comment: i dont understoond you can you explain more cause i dont know what is foo and bar

Comment: Those are just examples for the variables/strings/values. I would actually recommend that you go through some PHP 101 tutorials (there are plenty if you google) since using variables are one of the most fundamental parts.

Comment: the variables are not in same file thats why @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: If they're not in the same file, then the other file needs to be included in the first one for you to gain access to that variable. But in that case, the question is do you really need a duplicate variable or you could just continue using `$titleid`.

Comment: i need to do that cause i dint want to edit file by file wen i change example title @El_Vanja igualmente ya resolvieron mi duda gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
<?php $title="<?php echo $titleid; ?>"; ?>
```

You should not use the `echo`, since at that time you don't want any output. Also avoid the double `<?php ?>` brackets.

Just write that line as

```
<?php $title=$titleid; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you open <?php tag only once in file.  if you want get

## example title

in your pages, you define this content one variable and then get result with echo :
Ex

```
<?php 

$title = "<h1>example title</h1>";
echo $title;
```